# How can I return the user to the login page if they click 'Cancel'?

Tags: twitter, opencart, hybridauth

I am using an [OpenCart HybridAuth extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18378) to allow users to login using their Social Media login credentials. This has been implemented correctly and a user is able to create a new account, however if I click the cancel button when prompted to give permission to the application, it leads me to a black page (URL Parameters: ?route=hybrid/auth&provider=Twitter):

[image: Cancel Button]

How can I fix this so that it leads me back to either the login page?

Comment: where is goes right now ?.. You can change the URL of this cancel button form this controller file.

Comment: just find that button in the `.tpl` file and override the URL (it's either the one in the containing form or in the `onclick` event), If you can't, then  associate an action to the click event (using jQuery) of that button that stops the default action `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @NipunTyagi @Abdo Adel, I cannot change the `onclick` events or the `action` as the cancel button is located on Twitter itself, not within my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires a lot of work and time for me to setup an environment such as yours, but here what I was going to do any way, open the controller corresponding to this route `hybrid/auth` , trace what happens when the `provider` value is `"Twitter"`, dump the request data using `error_log(print_r($this->request, true))` , see which line causes the error, catch it and redirect the user to the login page, also I'm pretty sure that the plugin you are using has some setting that specifies the redirection link for the cancel button